# installing sveltekit error unexpected identifier. my bad or theres?

Tags: npm, svelte, sveltekit

Is there something I can do to get sveltekit to install?

I get

```
C:\dev\svelt\sOverstand>npm create svelte@latest sOverstand
npx: installed 7 in 9.849s
C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\9532\node_modules\create-svelte\bin.js:2
import fs from 'node:fs';
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
```

Comment: What is your Node version? I think the minimum supported version has been raised. Might have something to do with this.

Comment: @H.B. Thanks. 
I'm on windows 10. Tried with nodist and nvm with 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 12.13.1, 16.12.0, 16.13.1 all according to videos and other pages.
In the case of 16 I get a message that it only works with (gives a list of lower versions)  ...11, 12.

Comment: Same problem with npm init svelte@next myProj